# Crop video swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am recording a video in a square UIView but when I export the video is full screen 1080x1920 now I am wondering how I can reduce the video from being full screen to being square ratio 1:1...

Here is how I am setting my Video Camera up :

```
session = AVCaptureSession()
        for device in AVCaptureDevice.devices() {

            if let device = device as? AVCaptureDevice , device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {

                self.device = device
            }
        }

        for device in AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) {
            let device = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            let audioInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            session?.addInput(audioInput)
        }

        do {

            if let session = session {
                videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)

                session.addInput(videoInput)

                videoOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
                let totalSeconds = 60.0 //Total Seconds of capture time
                let timeScale: Int32 = 30 //FPS

                let maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(totalSeconds, timeScale)


                videoOutput?.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration
                videoOutput?.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024//SET MIN FREE SPACE IN BYTES FOR RECORDING TO CONTINUE ON A VOLUME

                if session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
                    session.addOutput(videoOutput)
                }


                let videoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
                videoLayer?.frame = self.videoPreview.bounds

                videoLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

                self.videoPreview.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer!)

                session.startRunning()
```

I have seen several other posts but not found them very helpfull, and most of them are in Obj C...

If anyone can help me or put me in the correct direction it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly you need to make use of the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`.

You specifically use the `func capture( _ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error! )` method to perform the cropping process, once the video has finished recording.

Here is an example of a cropping function I once implemented. You need to pass in the URL of the video that was recorded and a callback that is used to return the new URL of the cropped video once the cropping process is finished.

```
   func cropVideo( _ outputFileUrl: URL, callback: @escaping ( _ newUrl: URL ) -> () )
   {
       // Get input clip
       let videoAsset: AVAsset = AVAsset( url: outputFileUrl )
       let clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks( withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo ).first! as AVAssetTrack

       // Make video to square
       let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
       videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize( width: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, height: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height )
       videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake( 1, self.framesPerSecond )

       // Rotate to portrait
       let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction( assetTrack: clipVideoTrack )
       let transform1 = CGAffineTransform( translationX: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, y: -( clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width - clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height ) / 2 )
       let transform2 = transform1.rotated(by: CGFloat( M_PI_2 ) )
       transformer.setTransform( transform2, at: kCMTimeZero)

       let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
       instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds( self.intendedVideoLength, self.framesPerSecond ) )

       instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
       videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]

       // Export
       let croppedOutputFileUrl = URL( fileURLWithPath: FileManager.getOutputPath( String.random() ) )
       let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
       exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
       exporter.outputURL = croppedOutputFileUrl
       exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

       exporter.exportAsynchronously( completionHandler: { () -> Void in
           DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
               callback( croppedOutputFileUrl )
           })
       })
   }
```

Also, here is the implementation of my `getOutputPath` method:

```
func getOutputPath( _ name: String ) -> String
{
    let documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(      .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true )[ 0 ] as NSString
    let outputPath = "\(documentPath)/\(name).mov"
    return outputPath
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for that looking into it now, may I ask you what  FileManager.getOutputPath( String.random() is ?

Comment: hey Jack, FileManager is my custom class I implemented that handles file related stuff. FileManager.getOutputPath( String.random() ) takes a random String filename and and outputs a url path to that file. I updated my answer accordingly so you can see whats going on underneath it.

Comment: Figure it out seems to be good, I'm going to do a few more checks, if all good I'll accept! +1 for now Thanks alot

Comment: Oh I cannot upvote yet because of my rep... Soon as I have gained enough I shall upvote

Comment: Seems to be all good what frames per second would you reccomend? And can I ask you if you know how to resize the quality? the video is saved as HighestQuality which is about 1080x1080 and if I change it to medium quality I get 460x460 but I was hoping to get around 720x720... Any idea how to get that?

Answer (score 2):

```
func cropFrame(videoAsset:AVAsset, animation:Bool) -> Void {
    var insertTime = kCMTimeZero
    var arrayLayerInstructions:[AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction] = []
    var outputSize = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 0)

    // Determine video output size
    let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: videoTrack.preferredTransform)

    var videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
    if assetInfo.isPortrait == true {
        videoSize.width = videoTrack.naturalSize.height
        videoSize.height = videoTrack.naturalSize.width
    }

    if videoSize.height > outputSize.height {
        outputSize = videoSize
    }

    let defaultSize = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080) // Default video size

    if outputSize.width == 0 || outputSize.height == 0 {
        outputSize = defaultSize
    }

    // Silence sound (in case of video has no sound track)
    let silenceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "silence", withExtension: "mp3")
    let silenceAsset = AVAsset(url:silenceURL!)
    let silenceSoundTrack = silenceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first

    // Init composition
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition.init()


    // Get audio track
    var audioTrack:AVAssetTrack?
    if videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).count > 0 {
        audioTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first
    }
    else {
        audioTrack = silenceSoundTrack
    }

    // Init video & audio composition track
    let videoCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                               preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let audioCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio,
                                                               preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    do {
        let startTime = kCMTimeZero
        let duration = videoAsset.duration

        // Add video track to video composition at specific time
        try videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, duration),
                                                   of: videoTrack,
                                                   at: insertTime)

        // Add audio track to audio composition at specific time
        if let audioTrack = audioTrack {
            try audioCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, duration),
                                                       of: audioTrack,
                                                       at: insertTime)
        }

        // Add instruction for video track
        let layerInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: videoCompositionTrack!,
                                                                   asset: videoAsset,
                                                                   standardSize: outputSize,
                                                                   atTime: insertTime)
        // Hide video track before changing to new track
        let endTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, duration)
        //let finalTimer = CMTimeAdd(CMTime(seconds: 5, preferredTimescale: videoAsset.duration.timescale), CMTime(seconds: 5, preferredTimescale: videoAsset.duration.timescale))

        //Kalpesh crop video frames
        if animation {
            let timeScale = videoAsset.duration.timescale
            let durationAnimation = CMTime.init(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: timeScale)
            layerInstruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 1.0, toEndOpacity: 0.0, timeRange: CMTimeRange.init(start: endTime, duration: durationAnimation))

            //**********======== CROP YOUR VIDEO FRAME HERE MANUALLY ========**********

            layerInstruction.setCropRectangle(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoTrack.naturalSize.width, height: 300.0), at: startTime)
        } else {
            layerInstruction.setOpacity(0, at: endTime)
        }
        arrayLayerInstructions.append(layerInstruction)

        // Increase the insert time
        insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, duration)
    }
    catch {
        print("Load track error")
    }


    // Main video composition instruction
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, insertTime)
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = arrayLayerInstructions

    // Main video composition
    let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    mainComposition.renderSize = outputSize

    // Export to file
    let path = NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("mergedVideo.mp4")
    let exportURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path)


    // Init exporter
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession.init(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter?.outputURL = exportURL
    exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter?.videoComposition = mainComposition

    // Do export
    exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {

    })
}


func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset, standardSize:CGSize, atTime: CMTime) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
    let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

    let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: transform)

    var aspectFillRatio:CGFloat = 1
    if assetTrack.naturalSize.height < assetTrack.naturalSize.width {
        aspectFillRatio = standardSize.height / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
    }
    else {
        aspectFillRatio = standardSize.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
    }

    if assetInfo.isPortrait {
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: aspectFillRatio, y: aspectFillRatio)

        let posX = standardSize.width/2 - (assetTrack.naturalSize.height * aspectFillRatio)/2
        let posY = standardSize.height/2 - (assetTrack.naturalSize.width * aspectFillRatio)/2
        let moveFactor = CGAffineTransform(translationX: posX, y: posY)

        instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(moveFactor), at: atTime)

    } else {
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: aspectFillRatio, y: aspectFillRatio)

        let posX = standardSize.width/2 - (assetTrack.naturalSize.width * aspectFillRatio)/2
        let posY = standardSize.height/2 - (assetTrack.naturalSize.height * aspectFillRatio)/2
        let moveFactor = CGAffineTransform(translationX: posX, y: posY)

        var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(moveFactor)

        if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
            let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
            concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(moveFactor)
        }

        instruction.setTransform(concat, at: atTime)
    }
    return instruction
}
func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
    var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
    var isPortrait = false
    if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .right
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .left
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .up
    } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .down
    }
    return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
}
```

**Call this way:**

```
    let avssets = AVAsset(url: VideoURL)
    self.cropFrame(videoAsset: avssets, animation: true)
```