# How to crop video frame size from selected area in swift?

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, crop, avcapturesession

I'm working on video editing application. I want to crop a video by giving selected area but couldn't find any solution.

What I am trying to do right now is rotate, crop and toggle the video.
I managed to rotate and toggle but I am stuck in cropping.
The piece of codes that I have found only crops from top centre and bottom.
I want my texture view to be drag anywhere on the frame of the video gets the coordinates map that coordinates in to pixel and crop.

Please refer any approach or solution. 
Thanks
[image]

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40959810/5362916

Comment: @UmaMadhavi thanks for your response, but this solution is for center cropping. I need to crop form selected area .

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this yourself? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Magnas Yes, I've tried a lot.
What I am trying to do right now is rotate, crop and toggle the video.
I managed to rotate and toggle but I am stuck in cropping.
The piece of codes that I have found only crops from top centre and bottom.
I want my texture view to be drag anywhere on the frame of the video gets the coordinates map that coordinates in to pixel and crop.

Comment: @NaseerAttari did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @AbdulJamil nope.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but I'll reply in case it might help someone else.

You can use `AVMutableVideoComposition(.., applyingCIFiltersWithHandler)` to  apply Core Image Filters like `CICrop`, `CILanczosScaleTransform` to crop your video asset then export your generated composition as new video file

Let me give you an example code:

```
typealias CropTaskCompletion = (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void

// Calculate video frame (center it)
func cropVideoWithGivenSize(asset: AVAsset, baseSize cropSize: CGSize, completionHandler: @escaping CropTaskCompletion) {
    
    // Create your context and filter
    // I'll use metal context and CIFilter
    if let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
       let filterCrop = CIFilter(name: "CICrop") {
        context = CIContext(mtlDevice: device, options: [.workingColorSpace : NSNull()])
        cropFilter = filterCrop
    }
    
    // Try getting first video track to get size and transform
    guard let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
        print("No video track to crop.")
        completionHandler(.failure(NSError()))
        return
    }
    // Original video size
    let videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize.applying(videoTrack.preferredTransform)
    
    // Create a mutable video composition configured to apply Core Image filters to each video frame of the specified asset.
    let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { [weak self] request in
        
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
                    
        // Compute scale and corrective aspect ratio
        let scaleX = cropSize.width / videoSize.width
        let scaleY = cropSize.height / videoSize.height
        let rate = max(scaleX, scaleY)
        let width = videoSize.width * rate
        let height = videoSize.height * rate
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        // Handle video frame (CIImage)
        let outputImage = request.sourceImage
        
        // Define your crop rect here
        // I would like to crop video from it's center
        let cropRect = CGRect(
            x: (targetSize.width - cropSize.width) / 2,
            y: (targetSize.height - cropSize.height) / 2,
            width: cropSize.width,
            height: cropSize.height
        )
        
        // Add the .sourceImage (a CIImage) from the request to the filter.
        self.cropFilter.setValue(outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        // Specify cropping rectangle with converting it to CIVector
        self.cropFilter.setValue(CIVector(cgRect: cropRect), forKey: "inputRectangle")
        
        // Move the cropped image to the origin of the video frame. When you resize the frame (step 4) it will resize from the origin.
        let imageAtOrigin = self.cropFilter.outputImage!.transformed(
            by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: -cropRect.origin.x, y: -cropRect.origin.y)
        )
        
        request.finish(with: imageAtOrigin, context: self.context)
    })
    
    // Update composition render size
    composition.renderSize = cropSize
    
    // Export cropped video with AVAssetExport session
    guard let export = AVAssetExportSession(
        asset: asset,
        presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    else {
        print("Cannot create export session.")
        completionHandler(.failure(NSError()))
        return
    }
    
    let videoName = "Write_Your_Video_Name_Here"
    let exportURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        .appendingPathComponent(videoName)
        .appendingPathExtension("mp4") // Change file extension
    
    // Try to remove old file if exist
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: exportURL)
    
    // Assign created mutable video composition to exporter
    export.videoComposition = composition
    export.outputFileType = .mp4 // Change file type (it should be same with extension)
    export.outputURL = exportURL
    export.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false
    
    export.exportAsynchronously {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch export.status {
            case .completed:
                completionHandler(.success(exportURL))
                break
            default:
                print("Something went wrong during export.")
                if let error = export.error {
                    completionHandler(.failure(error))
                } else {
                    completionHandler(.failure(NSError(domain: "unknown error", code: 0, userInfo: nil)))
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can change this code to fit your purposes, I think that's enough to give an idea about how to crop with Core Image Filters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to apply a [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cifilter) ([CICrop](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CICrop)) to your video ? The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-DontLinkElementID_8) explain how to do that.

Comment: This is particularly related image filtering not related to my question. thanks

Comment: @NaseerAttari this related with video cropping also, have you tried to edit video composition by calling `applyingCIFiltersWithHandler` . You can do what ever you want with built-in & custom CIFilters to your video compositions.