# Swift video cropping in portrait mode

Tags: ios, video, orientation, video-editing, swift5

Video gets distorted when we are cropping the video. We are following [Crop video swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958848/crop-video-swift) this URL.

When we are cropping the landscape and screen recorded video, it works fine. But in the case of the portrait, it gets distorted.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it by using [PryntTrimmerView](https://github.com/HHK1/PryntTrimmerView) SDK